# sticky AlertDialog in android

Tags: android

In my app I want a 'sticky', that is to be always on top and to not dismiss once I accidentally tap on the background view, `AlertDialog`. Following the responses to various similar questions in stack-overflow I came up with that:

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // .. 
    AlertDialog alert_dialog = alert.create();
    alert_dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_DIALOG);
    alert_dialog.show();
```

and added this to my manifest file (otherwise the app would crash):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Still, I can't get the desired effect. The dialog does dismiss whenever I tap on the background view. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try to use `alert_dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);`

Comment: @Marinos try above line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [setCanceledOnTouchOutside()](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=android.app.AlertDialog&method=setCanceledOnTouchOutside)

Just add the following code before showing the dialog

```
alert_dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
alert_dialog.show();
```